# Configuring celery with systemd in Ubuntu - module path failure

Tags: django, ubuntu, celery, systemd

I use Ubuntu Server 18.04,Django, and I want to use celery with systemd .

I have the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ph'
May 02 21:02:55 ph-1c1m1t sh[2646]: Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I know that is a path error, but I tried multiple combinations regarding app, and I couldn't solve it.

the project structure is:

```
username
 -projects
    -src
      - ph  
        - settings (folder)
        - celery.py 
        -urls.py
```

**The conf file**

```
CELERYD_NODES="w1 w2"
CELERY_BIN="/home/username/env/prod/bin/celery"
CELERY_APP="ph.celery:app"
CELERYD_MULTI="multi"
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n%I.log"
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"
```

**In systemd, celery.service I have:**

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=username
Group=username
WorkingDirectory=/home/username/env/prod/
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/celery/celery.conf
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi stopwait ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE}'
ExecReload=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi restart ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Don't delete questions with answers. The person posting the answer has gone to effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the `PYTHONPATH` in your `/etc/celery/celery.conf`. This should point at the folder containing the `ph` package.

```
PYTHONPATH=/home/username/projects/src
CELERYD_NODES="w1 w2"
CELERY_BIN="/home/username/env/prod/bin/celery"
CELERY_APP="ph.celery:app"
CELERYD_MULTI="multi"
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n%I.log"
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"
```